# Info on LESS Mixins

Tags: less

Just a (hopefully) quick question about LESS Mixins:
Could these two mixins be combined somehow?, since they share a lot of the same information, just one adds an extra color.

```
.gradient-top(@color-1, @color-2){
    background-color: @color-2;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @color-1, @color-2);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @color-1, @color-2);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, @color-1, @color-2);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, @color-1, @color-2);
    background: linear-gradient(top, @color-1, @color-2);
}

.gradient-middle(@color-1, @color-2, @color-3){
    background-color: @color-2;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @color-1, @color-2, @color-3);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @color-1, @color-2, @color-3);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, @color-1, @color-2, @color-3);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, @color-1, @color-2, @color-3);
    background: linear-gradient(top, @color-1, @color-2, @color-3);    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LESS supports accessing all the arguments passed to a mixin via the `@arguments` variable:

```
.gradient(@color-1, @color-2, ...) {
    @gradient-stops: ~`"@{arguments}".slice(1, -1)`;
    background-color: @color-2;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @gradient-stops);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @gradient-stops);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, @gradient-stops);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, @gradient-stops);
    background: linear-gradient(top, @gradient-stops);
}
```

We need the selector interpolation (`~`) and the inline JavaScript evaluation (using backticks) to preserve the commas - otherwise, we would get `background: linear-gradient(top, #color-1 #color-2 #color-n);`, which is, of course, incorrect.

The other thing this mixin does is accept 2 *or more* arguments via the "rest" symbol (`...`) - this lets us call the mixing with three colors as well as two:

```
.gradient(#FFF, #CCC, #000) // A valid invocation of the mixin
```

Comment: So calling `.gradient(#000, #111)` gives me `background: linear-gradient(top, #000, #111)` and calling `.gradient(#000, #111, #000)` gives `background: linear-gradient(top, #000, #111, #000)` ?

Comment: @EricWolf - yes, it will indeed :-)

Comment: I tried to integrate "top" into the variable call, using (@direction, @fallback color, ...) and now can't get it to work. How to I feed the direction to the variable?